# What is the difference between <%# and <%= in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between <%# and <%= in ASPX inline code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<%= is shorthand for Response.Write()

<%# is used to render data in databound controls