# What is the difference between <% %> and <%= %> in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between <% %> and <%=%>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and)
>   [C# MVC: What is the difference between <%# and <%=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942166/c-mvc-what-is-the-difference-between-and)

I'm so confused with this.

Please explain the difference between this if possible..

What is the significance of that "=" there?

Edit:Thanks for all your answers.Please understand that It was hard to get any results by searching for "<%=" on google and on the search bar in stackoverflow as well.

Comment: This is a dupe for sure but I'm still struggling to find it.

Comment: Will: searching for punctuation chars is hard. discussed on meta.

Comment: And what about `<%# %>` !? That one is just crazy.

Comment: Kobi: hopefully, in ASP.NET MVC, we don't see that one most of the time! Also, there's `<%$ %>`.

Comment: I know its hard searching for this, thats why I didn't even bother looking for dupes.

Comment: See my post below. Searching for "asp.net bee stings" finds a couple of matches: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+bee+stings

Comment: Because no search engine in the world, including google and msdn, know how to look for it.  I believe the internal MSFT slang for these things, btw, is "nuggets."

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: Dup also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942166/c-mvc-what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: Very few people know the fact about bee stings....

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`<% %>` is a generic code block.

`<%= expression %>` is equivalent to `<% Response.Write(expression); %>`.

Answer (score 8):

It is confusing, and it takes a good deal of repetition to get comfortable with.

The <%= syntax is used for evaluating expressions whose returned values are intended to be included within HTML markup. For example:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>
```

This will include the current date in the HTML markup.

The <% is for inline statements, where you want to execute one or more commands at a specific point during the page rendering.  I've used Html Helpers in the past by executing the helper method using <%.  For example,

```
<% Html.TextBox("txtBox"); %>
```

Note that the statements used here have to be terminated with a semicolon in C# code.

**EDIT:** Removed erroneous details about Html helpers and void returns.

Comment: Actually, almost all of the Html Helpers return a string rather than writing to the Response object - <%= Html.TextBox("txtBox") %>. This allows you to e.g. nest helper methods.

Comment: `<% Html.TextBox("txtBox"); %>` silently discards the return value and doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 3):

<%= %> tag prints the output of the code in it, <% %> just runs the code.

Answer (score 3):

This post lists all the varieties nicely: [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags).

I would normally post this as a comment but there are a number of other dupes. I recall someone referring to them as "bee stings" (not official terminology) and the keywords I used to search for them were [asp.net bee stings](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+bee+stings).

That said, here are some other dupes:

- [What is the difference between <% %> and <%=%>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and)
- [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%#…what’s the deal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal)
- [When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls)